# How much do the COVID vaccines decrease the spread of SARS-CoV-2?

Tags: coronavirus, vaccination

The vaccines targeted at COVID-19 are measured against their ability to reduce the occurrence of the disease, COVID-19 (The Vaccine Efficiency or VE).  It does not measure its effect on the underlying virus' ability to spread.  From what I understand, this is the standard approach used for measuring the effectiveness of vaccines.  So called "sterilizing" vaccines, which prevent infection of others, are relatively rare.

From what I have read, it is generally accepted that the COVID-19 vaccines do indeed decrease the rate of transmission of SARS-CoV-2 (if I am understanding properly, this reproductive rate is typically given the label $R_T$, distinguishing it from $R_0$ which is the reproductive rate excluding any proactive behaviors we undertake).  However, I have not found any estimates as to how much it decreases transmission, which is an important number to estimate when projecting the long term behaviors of SARS-CoV-2 in society.

Are there any estimates to the effect the COVID-19 vaccines have on the reproductive rate of SARS-CoV-2 backed by studies?

Comment: https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-021-02054-z cites some Israeli studies stating that vaccinated, infected people are 78% less likely to transmit to members of their household than unvaccinated, infected people ...